# Offsite backup of Time Capsule

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule

I use the CrashPlan software to run backups of my NAS to an offsite machine.  I'd also like to use it for backing up a Time Capsule to the remote machine.

How do I do this so I don't impede Time Machine's backups?

My Time Capsule is a disk on a Mac Mini Server that backs up an MBP.  I've tried backing up the file `Time Machine Backups/Backups.backupdb` to a remote machine with CrashPlan, but this causes Time Machine on the connected clients to stop working.

How can I backup a Time Capsule?

Answer (score 1):

Time Capsule supports copying backups stored on it to an external USB-disk (put in the USB-port on the device).

You need to trigger it through the Airport Tool.

After copying the copy can be used as a Time Machine disk when restoring files or reinstalling OS X.

(I do not use the TC as a network disk, so any files stored there, must be manually copied)